# "NameError: uninitialized constant" when trying to include a concern in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, activesupport-concern, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to include a Concern inside a Rails ApplicationRecord object.

Here is the model file: /app/models/item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  include Items::Validating
end
```

Here is the concern file: /app/models/concerns/items/validating.rb

```
module Items
  module Validating

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      before_create :set_defaults
      validates :status, presence: true
      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates :day, presence: true
    end

    def set_defaults
      self.status ||= 'active'
      self.day ||= Date.today
    end

  end
end
```

When I try to run tests, I get the following error:

```
$ rails t

Error:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_session:
NameError: uninitialized constant Item::Items
    app/models/item.rb:3:in `<class:Item>'
    app/models/item.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

It's weird, because I'm including concerns on the User model and it's working completely normally. I can't figure out what's different here.

---

Update: there are no errors when running the server or console, it is only when running tests. Here is the SessionsControllerTest file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @session = sessions(:one)
  end

  test "should fail to create session because of no email" do
    assert_difference('Session.count', 0) do
      post sessions_url, params: { email: 'no-email-found@no-email.com', password: 'password_hashed' }
    end

    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should fail to create session because of no password" do
    assert_difference('Session.count', 0) do
      post sessions_url, params: { email: 'jerry@vandalay.com', password: 'password_hashed_wrong' }
    end

    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should create session" do
    email = 'jerry@vandalay.com'
    assert_difference('Session.count') do
      post sessions_url, params: { email: email, password: 'password_hashed' }
    end

    user = User.first_with_email(email)
    assert_redirected_to dashboard_url
  end

  test "should destroy session" do
    get logout_url

    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

end
```

Comment: The issue is about Rails' autoloading and the fact that it is loading different classes and namespaces in the context of your tests... Using `include ::Items::Validating` in your item model should fix this problem.

Comment: When I change it to `include ::Items::Validating` I get the following namespace error instead: `NameError: uninitialized constant Items`

Comment: Tested on a "fresh" Rails 6.0.0.beta1, Ruby 2.6.0 application and works fine. What else can you add to the question?

Comment: I am on Rails 6.0.0.beta1, but Ruby 2.5.1 instead of 2.6.0 - I will update Ruby and see if the error goes away. This is also a brand new repo, There is only 1 other model.

Comment: I tested it on Ruby 2.5.1, also works. What's in that SessionsControllerTest?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Updated the question. Appears to be a `rails test` issue, as there are no errors thrown when running the console or server.

Comment: Could you solve this? @secondbreakfast

Comment: @SebastianPalma No, I could not. :(

Comment: @secondbreakfast still not solved? Running into the same problem myself.